# Issues with using Java compare/contain methods

Tags: java, jena

Please, I am working on a project where I have to traverse an RDF(turtle format) and find a certain line from which I could store the preceeding lines from that line. Basically, I am to compare each traversing line with the string :

> "[ a       sswap:Subject , d:investment;"

.I tried the contains() method and the equals() method but both didn't work. I have written a simple Java code to do this. The only problem is even though it gets to the desired line, it doesn't go into the for loop to execute. This means the boolean is false but why? Could someone explain what I might be doing wrong?

```
    .
    .
    .
    if(line =="[ a  sswap:Subject , d:investment ;"){
                            do{

                                for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                                    if (line.charAt(i) == ';') {
                                        arr.add(line); //an arraylist
                                    }
                                }
                                line = it.nextLine(); //loop to the next line
                                //traverse through the characters in the line
                                //if the last character is ";"
                                //store that line.
                            }while(line!="]");
   .
   .
   .
```

Below is the line in the turtle i am trying to check in the if statement of the java code.

```
sswap:operatesOn [

rdf:type sswap:Graph ; sswap:hasMapping [

                rdf:type sswap:Subject, d:investment; //trying to capture this..
```

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood as he said he used equals

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin you are so right.

Comment: The way that you're doing this (processing the text of the file) doesn't have anything to do with Jena or RDF.  The RDF-based way to do this would be to ask for the resource s such that the graph contains two triples: `s rdf:type sswap:Subject` and `s rdf:type d:investment`.  That's not too hard to do using Jena.  Do you want a solution for doing that with Jena?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the line you are trying to compare to does not exact match

`rdf:type sswap:Subject, d:investment; //trying to capture this..`

vs

`[ a  sswap:Subject , d:investment ;`

then either use `contains` [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

or
`indexOf`
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score -1):

You are comparing string that has **empty spaces** use the trim to eliminate empty spaces before and after the string and then use the equals method of the string you are comparing;

**change this:**

```
line =="[ a  sswap:Subject , d:investment ;"
```

**to:**

```
line.trim().equals("[ a  sswap:Subject , d:investment ;")
```

But is it a good practise to **trim** the line of string first before comparing them

Answer (score -1):

Please assign the string to another variable and then compare it in IF statement. 
like,

```
String str="[ a  sswap:Subject , d:investment ;";
 if(line ==str)
    OR
 if(line.equals(str))
```